# Hibernate 6 mapping without annotations

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Up to Hibernate 5 the class mapping can be defined either by using JPA annotations or with an XML file. The XML file is convenient because it isn't tied to the class, which means it's possible to:

1. map a class even if you don't have the source code
2. map a class differently depending on the context (a class may be mapped one way on the server, and another way on the client)

Hibernate 6 removed the XML mapping. Is there an alternative method to define a mapping without adding annotations to the persisted classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now recommend the use of the standard JPA ORM mapping format, which is `orm.xml`.

For Hibernate-specific extensions to the `orm.xml` format you can find `mapping-3.1.0.xsd` here:

https://hibernate.org/xsd/orm/mapping/mapping-3.1.0.xsd

I guess this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I missed something hbm XML mappings are still in Hibernate 6 but now they are officially deprecated: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#_deprecation_of_hbm_xml_mappings

Comment: Good point thank you, I thought that was removed. But that sounds a bit risky to keep using it if that's now unsupported.

Comment: My understanding is that they plan to extend the `orm.xml` standard JPA mapping, but that's not going to happen anytime soon. Also beware that the appetite to fix bugs in hbm mappings is low, I've hit one on Hibernate 5 and had to migrate from hbm to annotations